# ComponentDidUpdate is not working while updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a configured list with location details. After initial retrieving the details,if i delete any location item or items and update it. It is not taking updated value. I think componentdidupdate is not working properly. How to resolve it

Component code:

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
               open:false,
               configuredList:[],
               clearList:[]
        };
       this.configLocation = this.configLocation.bind(this);
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.removeConfigLocation = this.removeConfigLocation.bind(this);
        //this.removeLocationAll = this.removeLocationAll.bind(this);
    }

    togglePanel (e){
        this.setState({open : !this.state.open});
    }
    handleRemove(mruCode){
        this.props.removeLocation(mruCode)
     }
    handleClick (mruCode){
      this.props.addLocation(mruCode)
     }
     allLocations (){
       this.props.addAllLocation()
    }
    clearall (){
        this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if(this.props.locationData !=null && this.props.locationData!= undefined){
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
      }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        console.log(prevProps);
        if (prevProps.locationData != this.props.locationData) {
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
            console.log(this.props.locationData);
        }

    }

    configLocation(locationData){
        let configuredList =[];
        if(locationData.locations.locationDetails != null && locationData.locations.locationDetails !=undefined ){
            configuredList = locationData.locations.locationDetails;
        }
        else if(locationData.locations.locationDetails === null){
            configuredList = [];
        }
        this.setState({configuredList});
    }

    removeConfigLocation(index){
        this.setState(({configuredList})=>{
            let remList = [...configuredList]
            remList.splice(index,1)
            return {
                configuredList:remList
            }
        })
    }


    getLocationData(){
         let saveableLocationlist = [];
         if(this.props.locationData === null){
             saveableLocationlist = [];
         }
        const locationData = {
            locationDetails : saveableLocationlist
        }
      return locationData;
    }

    render(){
        //const{configuredList} = this.state;
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)}>
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                     <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                     </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                        <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.state.configuredList.map((loc,index)=><span key={index}>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}</span>)}
                           <span onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                   </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
              {this.state.open?(
                        <div className="panel-body">
                             <div className="row grid-divider">
                             <div className="col-sm-6">
                             <div className="col-padding"><div className="pos-div"><h3>Locations List</h3><button style={{ display: this.props.location.length === this.props.conLocations.length ? "none" : "block" }} className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>{this.allLocations()}}>Add all locations</button></div><hr/>
                             {this.props.location.map((item,index)=>(
                             <div key={index}><div><b>{item.mruCode} - {_labels[item.division]} - {item.country}</b>{!this.props.conLocations.find(item2 => item.mruCode === item2.mruCode)&&(<div className="pull-right jd"><button style={{ display: this.state.configuredList.find(item3=> item.mruCode===item3.mruCode) ? "none" : "block" }} className="call-to-action" onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(item.mruCode)}}>Add Location</button></div>)}<hr/></div></div>))}
                            </div>
                             </div> 
                                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                                  <div className="col-padding">
                                  <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>this.clearall()}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
              <div><table className="table"><thead>{this.state.configuredList.map((locc,index)=><tr key={index}><th><b>{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</b></th><th className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>{this.removeConfigLocation(index)}} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></th></tr>)}</thead><tbody>
                        {this.props.conLocations.map((loct,index)=><tr key={index}>
                           <td><b>{loct.mruCode} - {_labels[loct.division]} - {loct.country}</b></td>
                           <td className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>this.handleRemove(loct.mruCode)}className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody></table></div>

                                   </div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div> 
                    </div>):null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations:state.locationRed.conLocations
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(addLocation(mruCode))},
        addAllLocation:() =>{dispatch(addAllLocation())},
        removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
        removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())}
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps,null,{withRef:true})(NewLocationPanel);
```

While checking console.log(this.props.locationData) in componentDidUpdate method, initially it is giving the list items. After delete any item if i save the changes then it is giving same list items with deleted item too. how to make it work?

Comment: if `this.props.locationData` in the componentDidUpdate isn't what you expect it to be then the issue is happening somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're updating `this.props.locationData` on in `removeConfigLocation` (or anywhere other than the initial `GET`). To be honest, it looks like the way you're leveraging `locationData` should be put into `state` instead of `props`.

Also you should note that you're blowing out your state in these lines:

```
// before: this.state={ open:false, configuredList:[], clearList:[] };
this.setState(({configuredList})=>{
    let remList = [...configuredList]
    remList.splice(index,1)
    return {
        configuredList:remList
    }
})
// after: this.state={ configuredList: remList};
```

You should make sure you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...this.state`) if you want to keep it available after the update.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. I understood but not able to figure out how to make it happen the update part. Will you please help me on this? In removeConfigLocation How to update locationData or save changes while removing